# acceptSslCerts in Webdriver 3 using java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

With Firefox: 48.0.1 and webdriver 3 beta
I tried to execute this code:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws WebDriverException{
    WebDriver driver;
    String baseUrl ="https://192.168.100.82/";
    try{
        DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        dc.setCapability("acceptSslCerts", true);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);
        driver.get(baseUrl);
    }catch(WebDriverException e){
        System.out.println("WebDriverException: "+e);
        }
    }
}
```

but I got this exception:

```
1472445033581   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 60392
1472445037082   Marionette  INFO    startBrowser 0232958c-f634-4675-a014-08768127bb33
1472445037092   Marionette  INFO    sendAsync 0232958c-f634-4675-a014-08768127bb33
1472445037745   Marionette  INFO    sendAsync 0232958c-f634-4675-a014-08768127bb33
1472445037813   Marionette  INFO    sendAsync 0232958c-f634-4675-a014-08768127bb33        
WebDriverException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error loading page (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 824 milliseconds
    Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '2aa21c1', time: '2016-08-02 14:59:43 -0700'
    System info: host: 'windows-PC', ip: '172.16.16.2', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
    Capabilities [{rotatable=false, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false, appBuildId=20160823121617, version=, platform=XP, proxy={}, command_id=1, specificationLevel=0, acceptSslCerts=false, browserVersion=48.0.2, platformVersion=6.1, XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, browserName=Firefox, takesScreenshot=true, takesElementScreenshot=true, platformName=Windows_NT, device=desktop}]
    Session ID: 0232958c-f634-4675-a014-08768127bb33
```

And the result is:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far Marionette does not support self-signed certificates. It is in the [roadmap](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1103196), but not implemented yed.